# Reverse dry shake, when and what for?

Tags: cocktails, terminology, recipes

I noticed in a coctail recipe that it said to *"reverse dry shake"* the drink. My question is: **when do you do this** (what types of drinks), and **what is the purpose of this?** Is there instances where you want to reverse dry shake but *not* dry shake?

In a "normal" dry shake you would shake the ingredients whitout ice, and this is then usually followed by a "normal" shake with ice afterwards. As I understand, the purose of this has to do with temperature. For instance, eggwhite mixes with ingredients better at higher temperature (without ice). So for drinks with eggwhite you want to dry shake first to properly mix the ingredients and then shake "normally" (w/ ice) to cool the drink.

**My understanding is that** a reverse dry shake is to shake first with ice and then shake one more time without ice after; in other words, the reverse of a normal dry shake procedure. I can't think of a good reason you would do this instead of dryshaking normaly. My only guess is that it makes the drink more "airy" or foamy because of shaking without ice. But can't this effect be obtained if you dry shake first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the main purpose is preserving the foam.

[Why the Reverse Shake Yields Perfect Egg White Foam](https://talesofthecocktail.org/techniques/why-reverse-shake-yields-perfect-egg-white-foam/)